# How to use "--dart-define=" in Flutter test

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-test

I'm using flutter test with `--dart-define` option as follows:

```sh
# code to run the test
flutter test --machine --start-paused --plain-name "" --dart-define=SOMEENVVAR=123 test/rovaf_client_test.dart
```

but the problem is that I can't use this environment variable as follows:

```dart
print(String.fromEnvironment("SOMEENVVAR"));
```

this just prints out nothing.

Is there any way to use environment variable or pass parameters for `flutter run test` command? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need a const for environment variable.

```
print(const String.fromEnvironment("SOMEENVVAR"));
```

Please refer to this:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/55870#issuecomment-620776138