# How to use --dart-define-from-file in Flutter test

Tags: flutter, dart, testing

This is NOT the same question as [How to use --dart-define in Flutter test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70299229/how-to-use-dart-define-in-flutter-test)

Using the Flutter 3.7 release, I am loading config/env variables to my Flutter app at runtime using the command `flutter run --dart-define-from-file=config.json`. For testing, how would I make sure a test config file is loading at runtime?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new separate configuration file ("test_config.json" for example) that contains the test environment variables to be loaded during testing.

```
flutter test --dart-define-from-file=test_config.json
```

Make sure to load the proper configuration file in your app. Assuming that you are using [`flutter_config`](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_config):

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await FlutterConfig.loadEnvVariables();

  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

It ensures that the test configuration file is loaded at runtime during testing, allowing testing with the desired environment variables or configurations.

---

Additionally, you could use the `loadValueForTesting` in the `flutter_config` package to load mock variables:

```
void main() {
  FlutterConfig.loadValueForTesting({'BASE_URL': 'https://www.mockurl.com'});
  
  test('mock http client test', () {
    final client = HttpClient(
      baseUrl: FlutterConfig.get('BASE_URL')
    );
  });
}
```